# A word for the quality of being easy or good to talk to

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, expression-choice

**What is a word for the quality of being easy or good to talk to?**

It is more than just being a "good listener." And it is not "open-minded," in that it's not about being receptive to new ideas.

The context: In David Foster Wallace's *The Pale King*, there is a scene in which two colleagues - a man and woman - are chatting in a bar. The man is described thus:

"...he has the quality of being easy or good to talk to, which is an attribute for which there is no good single word in English, which is slightly odd, although so is whatever is good about talking to Drinion, since he possesses nothing that could be called charm or social grace or even evident compassion."

So this got me to thinking... what is a good word for this type of person? He's not charming or particularly affable. He's just the kind of person that you find yourself opening up to in conversation.

Somehow reassuring to see Wallace lexically stumped.

Comment: _Affable_ is one such. Wallace, though a brilliant writer, was often wrong about language.

Comment: I agree that affable includes the concept of being easy to talk to, but it also includes the more active concept of "friendliness," which this word in question would not necessarily include.

Comment: "Attentive" and "considerate" would be two words I would use to describe someone that was easy to open up to.

Comment: If you're trying to define a concept that has footnotes embedded in it, it's hardly surprising that English doesn't have a single word to suit it.

Comment: "Cognizance" "cognition" could be used in the right context

Comment: @John, 90% of Wallace's output is footnotes.  Sometimes his footnotes, quite literally, have footnotes.

Comment: @Don: I think John was actually playing on that fact... still, it seems a clever way of saying "you're being too specific," a charge I will gladly accept. I mean, every time we search for the perfect word, we're thinking "no, not that one" and "no, that's not the right connotation..."

Comment: Actually, "a good listener" means exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

People such as the man described are easy-going, accommodating or even forbearing but, basically, if one is induced to converse freely with him, he is then also, in some way, seductive...

Comment: So if this man is your own dad, is he still seductive to you?

Comment: @Lambie -I don't exactly agree w/ your answer, but it brings up a strange thing that I've encountered... I often find myself in the position of having complete strangers tell me all about themselves, (TMI) with no prompting from me. In fact, I have terrible ADD, and I'm usually "somewhere else" after a few sentences. However, I am handicapped with very active facial expressions, and I tend to mimic anyone who is addressing me. This behavior may cause the speaker to believe I am empathetic, or friendly, or maybe even seductive (see: Chartrand and Bargh, "Chameleon effect"- but it's a reflex.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually more than one word (or phrase) in English to describe this.  However, some of them may carry unnecessary baggage that you don't want to express:

> [conversable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conversable)

MW: pleasant and easy to converse with

> [affable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affable?show=0&t=1417805164)

MW: being pleasant and at ease in talking to others

> [easygoing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affable?ref=dictionary&word=easy%20going#) [conversationalist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affable?ref=dictionary&word=conversationalist#)

MW: relaxed and casual in style or manner

MW: one who converses a great deal or who excels in conversation

> [heedful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heedful) (listener, conversationalist, etc.)

TFD: Paying close attention; mindful

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but how about "a good 'sounding board'?"

Comment: In what way would you say Drinion is being portrayed as a sounding board?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment - Of course there are technical meanings for 'sounding board', but it's also a figure of speech (commonly used in US) for someone that you bounce ideas and thoughts off (of).

Comment: Yes, a sounding board is definitely someone for bouncing ideas off, to get feedback. Not exactly the situation here.